# RuntimeException in Picasso with Android N

Tags: android, picasso

The issue is limited to sdk 24. Works with Android N Preview.

```
new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())).build();
```

throws

```
3885-4022/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Picasso-Dispatcher
     Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 3885
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1659)
         at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoExecutorService.setThreadCount(PicassoExecutorService.java:83)
         at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoExecutorService.adjustThreadCount(PicassoExecutorService.java:66)
         at com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.performNetworkStateChange(Dispatcher.java:401)
         at com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher$DispatcherHandler.handleMessage(Dispatcher.java:521)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: You might wish to create a sample project that can reproduce the problem, then [file an issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues). The sample project would be crucial, though, so Square knows the exact build settings that result in the failing app. From what you have shown here, I cannot see how this could be a problem in your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I could not reproduce the issue with a sample project. Also, the issue seems to happen on a Nexus 5X emulator running sdk 24, but works on a Nexus 5X running bullhead-npd56n.

Comment: :: shrug :: without a reproducible test case, I am not sure that anyone can help you.

Comment: I have the same crash, and it's pretty random. It happens often when my app is in the background.